Power Automate - When an item is created or modified - start on created and/or field is modified
I want to trigger a flow in two conditions:

When an item is created
When a certain field is modified.

The issue is that when I add a trigger condition such as when the RestartFlow is true:
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/RestartFlow'], true)

But adding this trigger condition means that the flow is only started when this condition is true.  It doesn't start when the item is created.  Is there a way to trigger the flow in both these conditions, when the item is created and when RestartFlow is modified.
Thank you,
Ricky

Could you just set the default value for RestartFlow to true? So when the item is created, RestartFlow is already true
